# .Net: Open .compiled file which is code behind the view page

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, precompiled-headers

compiled file in bin folder which is code behind page in my project.
I don't have source code. so I need to open my .compiled file to see code and If possible I need to change it.

How to open it to see code in it.

used Refactor tool which gives error.
"File is not a portable executable. DOS header does not contain 'MZ' signature."

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e22s60h9.aspx) says: _The .compiled file does not contain executable code. Instead, it contains only the information that ASP.NET needs to find the appropriate assembly._

Comment: @Jester msdn link help me.